# Code editor that supports cross-language (c)tags between C and python

Tags: python, c++, c, exuberant-ctags

What I have is a large amount of C code and a bunch of swig wrappers to export all the functions into python. We like using python for testing, it's great, but my problem is there don't seem to be any editors out there that will share tags between python and C.

What I want is to ctrl+click (or whatever shortcut) on a function in a *.py file and have it go to the function definition in a *.c file.

Geany seems to do an alright job of this but it has some limitations (poor gdb support, etc). Eclipse, netbeans, Qt Creator are all good editors for C (creator being my fav) but they don't support cross-language tags. Eclipse in particular supports python quite well in PyDev but a tag in python is totally separate from a tag in C, and I can't seem to find a way to make them share. Vim/emacs probably do due to the somewhat lower level ctags use but I don't like either of them.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure you'll find an IDE to support several syntax at the same time

Comment: If you won't use the universal IDEs (emacs and/or vim with all the bells and whistles) then you'll have a hard time finding an editor that does that.

Comment: @eresonance you might wanna check this out. may be it will help you
http://eclipse.org/Xtext

Comment: however I'd concern @randomusername 's suggestion if I were you. It's saving your time.

Comment: @randomusername I should qualify that I know how to use vim and use it on a regular basis (I have a fairly healthy .vimrc) but I don't like it.

If emacs/vim can do it, why can't other editors?

Comment: The reason that other editors don't is simply because they haven't been invested in enough.  Emacs and Vim both have been around far longer than many of the people who use them (myself and my peers are all in this category).  Throughout all that time, and thanks to their enormous popularity, the millions of man hours invested in them completely out paces anything that a modern IDE has been able to muster.

Comment: On Windows I use Zeus editor and it can handle ctags from multiple languages. But I suspect you're on Linux or OSX which might mean it will be now good for you. I've never tried but it might work on Linux using Wine?

Comment: Did you try `emacs`; I'm sure you configure it to suite your needs....

Answer (score 0):

I do this using UltraEdit, but UltraEdit is not great if you do not like it :-) Its not really an IDE more like an Editor. However the way I do it can most likely be ported to e.g. Eclipse.

I generate the Ctags file my self. and force UE to use the custom generated cTags file. This works like a charm.